# cannot reach EC2 instance in ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have created an ECS cluster and task definition and managed to boot up a single container for my app (ec2 launch type). However, I can't reach the public ip listed.

- EC2 Instance is green/running, status checks 2/2 passed. IPv4 public address listed.
- The public subnet and security group it is linked to allows http access and ssh from my ip for now.
- there is a database on a private subnet that the container should reach (private subnet SG allows incoming conns from the public subnet).

How can I troubleshoot and fix this? Thanks!

**EDITS** further info as requested:

- NACL: {100 allow all, * deny all} in that order.
- Subnet: auto-assign ipv4 address is on.
- can confirm *inside* the container, `curl localhost:PORT` WORKS.
- can confirm *inside* the container, `ping <rds db endpoint>` FAILS.
- can confirm that outside the container, hitting `public-ip:PORT` FAILS.

**EDITS 2** as requested:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
fa3dxxxxxxxx        xxx/xxx:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes              3010/tcp            xxx
9766yyyyyyyy        amazon/ecs-agent:latest  "/agent"         24 minutes ago      Up 24 minutes (healthy)                        ecs-agent
011axxxxxxxx        xxx/xxx:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Exited (137) 2 hours ago                       xxx
```

Can confirm `curl local-ip:PORT` FAILS:
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.0.x.x port xxxx: Connection refused`

Comment: is the instance in a public subnet?

Comment: Check your Security group and NACL. Also do you have fixed IP.? try opening source anywhere in SG just for test and check

Comment: @Marcin yes public subnet @ Sangam Elose I don't know what you mean by fixed ip - i don't think so? it's an auto-assigned ip i believe. Thanks!

Comment: What network mode are u using? `awsvpc`?

Comment: @Marcin just default bridge network. I just found another issue: `docker attach <containerid>` just hangs :( so maybe the container itself is borked.

Comment: so if you are able to ssh its mean instance is reachable, which sort of application is running inside container? are you able to test the following `docker ps` grab the container ID and then `docker exec -it container_id sh` once you inside container then run `curl localhost:PORT` if this is responding to localhost then its mean something wrong with application code,

Comment: @Adiii its just a nodejs app. Each time i use the docker commands suggested above the container stops, and i don't know how to restart it with all the environment variables that the ecs agent starts it with. even the ecs agent itself has stopped now. Going to try and restart from AWS console itself and report back.

Comment: @Adiii updated with more info.

Comment: so one thing is confirm that container working on `curl localhost:PORT WORKS.`

Comment: can you show the response of `docker ps` and also do one thing more is `curl private_IP:PORT` is responding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217943/discussion-between-yen-and-adiii).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the discussion, we investigate the issue.

The issue was in the task definition, the application was working inside the container but nor with host public and private IP address.

Publishing port in the task definition should resolve the issue.

```
{
  "ContainerPort" : 3010,
  "HostPort" : Integer,
  "Protocol" : 3010
}
```

> The `PortMapping` property specifies a port mapping. Port mappings allow containers to access ports on the host container instance to send or receive traffic. Port mappings are specified as part of the container definition.

[aws-containerdefinitions-portmappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html.html)

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, the missing port mapping was hiding the fact of a missing port rule in the security group as well (needed to allow incoming tcp from from the exposed port).